# Efficient summation without looping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, sum

I need to calculate entries for two long series consisting of sums. Currently I'm looping, which is rather inefficient. I was wondering whether there exists a `pandas` method to exploit. It follows an MWE.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
T = range(1, 8761)  # year in hours
T0 = range(6, 8761 + 24, 24)  # time instant such that storage is empty 
e2p = 2  # energy-to-power; maximal duration [h] such that storage can be emptied

# Input data: 
# on: maximal storageinflow
# off: maximal storageoutflow  
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(8760, 2)),
    index=T,
    columns=['on', 'off']
)

# Output
# sum1: maximal storage level for storage with fixed instants T0
# sum2: maximal storage level for e2p storage
df['sum1'] = np.nan
df['sum2'] = np.nan

# Summation 1
# Everything that flows in within s in [t, t + 23] for t in T0
# must flow out until s = t + 24  
for t in T0:
    t0 = max(1, t - 23)
    t = min(t, 8760)
    for s in range(t0, t + 1):
        sum_on = df.loc[t0: s, 'on'].sum()
        sum_off = df.loc[s + 1: t, 'off'].sum()
        df.loc[s, 'sum1'] = min(sum_on, sum_off)

# Summation 2
# Everything that flowed in until t in T, *can* flow out until t+e2p
for t in T:
    t0 = max(1, t - e2p + 1)
    tf = min(t + e2p, 8760)
    sum_on = df.loc[t0: t, 'on'].sum()
    sum_off = df.loc[t + 1: tf, 'off'].sum()
    df.loc[t, 'sum2'] = min(sum_on, sum_off)
```

**Solution Sum 1**

```
for t in T0:
    t0 = max(1, t - VZF + 1)
    t = min(t, 8760)
    sum_ein = df.loc[t0: t, 'on'].cumsum()
    sum_aus = (df.loc[t0: t, 'off']
               .iloc[::-1]
               .cumsum()
               .iloc[::-1]
               .shift(periods=-1, fill_value=0))
    df.loc[t0: t, 'sum1'] = pd.concat([sum_on, sum_off], axis=1).min(axis=1)
```

**Solution Sum 2**

```
sum_on = df['on'].rolling(window=e2p, min_periods=1).sum() 
sum_off = (df['off']
           .shift(periods=-1, fill_value=0)
           .iloc[::-1]
           .rolling(window=e2p, min_periods=1)
           .sum()
           .iloc[::-1])

df['sum2'] = pd.concat([sum_on, sum_off], axis=1).min(axis=1)
```

Comment: Could you give a textual description of what `sum1` and `sum2` are supposed to represent? Apparently they are partial daily sums of ..., but that is probably easier to infer from a succinct 1-line comment than from three nested levels of indexing (`T0`, `t`, `s`).

Comment: I've written a description. The `sum`s basically represent a maximal storage level.

Comment: Do you still seek improvements on your solutions? If not, you may as well post them as a self-answer. I was just now digging through the pandas docs in search for - basically - what you've un`roll`ed yourself.

Comment: To get rid of the final `for t in T0` loop, you probably would need to go fully numpy and extend your tables in another dimension. IMHO that's not worth it for a mere 365 iterations.

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to use numpy here and make it "unreadable" just for the sake of loop-freeness.